# select menu does not populate the top area if I have a v-model on it

Tags: vue.js

I am using vuejs and have a basic select menu that works fine.Issue is as soon as i add a v-model, the default name that says "choose option" disappear. Anyway to avoid this from happening, I tried populating the empty array with some text, but it still doesnt make any text display in the select menu label area.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   selections:[]
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
<select id="test"class="form-control" v-model="selection"  style="width: 110px;">
  <option value="Select a option" selected disabled>Choose an area:</option>
    <option v-for="t in todos" :value="a">{{ t.name }}</option>

</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your current code I did not see any `selection` property in data object, You have to assign `v-model` value as per your default first option value.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   selection: 'Select a option',
   todos: [{
    name: 'alpha'
   }, {
    name: 'beta'
   }, {
    name: 'gamma'
   }]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <select v-model="selection">
    <option value="Select a option" disabled>Choose an area:</option>
    <option v-for="(t, i) in todos" :key="i" :value="t.name">{{ t.name }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: i need selection to either remain and empty array selection:[] or figure out a way for this way to work   selection:['choose an area']

Comment: @Vzupo why do you want it as an array ? Your select is a single select and will always hold a single value. Hence, I did not see any use case of defining `selection` as an array.

Comment: What if we make it so that the 1st option is automatically selected when  it runs?  Is that more doable?

Comment: @Vzupo are you talking about the `options` array ? Its simple case - for single select and a single HTML element in whole component, no need to pass `v-model` as an array as that will always hold a single value.

Comment: as in the first item in the array. sorry for the confusion ('alpha')

Comment: I did not understand your requirement here. Just tell me one thing. what issue you are facing in above implementation. based on that only i can help you.